# Postgres System frozen in WALSync

Tags: postgresql, locking, wal

I've hit this issue three times in a row now and I don't know what is causing it.

Context: I am running large scripts and at some point the system gets stuck in a WALSync state. The best way to describe it is this view of pg_stat_activity

| pid | query | state | wait_event_type | wait_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5172 | (redacted) | active | LWLock | WALWrite |
| 1887 |  | NULL | Activity | LogicalLauncherMain |
| 1884 |  | NULL | IO | DataFileFlush |
| 1883 |  | NULL | IO | DataFileFlush |
| 1885 |  | NULL | IO | WALSync |

- Disk space isn't an issue.
- No transaction control is being used.
- The other times that this has happened have been on different queries (i.e. its not this specific query, but something about the load or something else?).
- The same scripts have been tested in a dev db (same machine and cluster) and work just fine.
- No other activity is happening on the system.
- I've tried cancelling and terminating all of the pid's and nothing happens.
- The only way to move forward is to restart the server :(((((
- No other/new queries can execute (besides things like pg_stat_activity).

About:

- Pgs 13.2
- EC2, Ubuntu, 8 Cores, 32GB RAM
- No replication.
- Machine is basically just a processing center, so I've tried to tune accordingly (but I am not an expert and any advice would be welcome) see below...

Non-default settings:

```
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 52428kB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 16GB
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8
max_parallel_workers = 8
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

Any ideas or insight into how I can dig further would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it absolutely frozen, making zero progress?  Or is it just slow, with WALSync being the main bottleneck?  What do things like `top`, `vmstat`, or `sar` show?

Comment: @jjanes Its completely silent. No activity on top. I haven't monitored `sar` yet, but am running a new build now and watching it.

I suspect that because these are EBS drives, that something might have caused a temporary lapse in accessibility without a way to resume. I don't know - just a hunch.

Comment: If the EBS was hosed, I would think you wouldn't be able to do much of anything at the system/command line level either.  Is this EBS just used for PostgreSQL data, with the OS and binaries living elsewhere?  What happens if you run `pg_test_fsync`, telling it to put the file on the same EBS where the PostgreSQL data lives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think resolved the issue with a configuration tweak. After I changed the `maintenance_work_mem` to 4GB, I ran the same scripts twice without any issues. For whatever that is worth.

Answer (score 0):

Your I/O system is overloaded.

If it is Linux, verify by running

```sh
sar -u 1 10
```

If `%iowait` is consistently in the two-digit range, you have proof.

Comment: Can you embellish that explanation? Currently the EBS mounts are pretty substantial and just from watching iotop I can tell that the system was almost always CPU bound (8 cores). Yet, yes I am seeing iowaits in the 10's and sometimes close to the 20's. Also, I've run these builds very hard a lot of times and never had an issue - the only thing I've done since is increased disk space and IOPS capacity since then. I'm not asking for you to solve my problem, but if you have any insight into what "overloaded" really means or how I can solve it, I would love that.

Comment: No, that's the hard part. All I can tell is that you won't get any more I/O out of that system, but I cannot say where the bottleneck is.